# My table works in latex in general but not in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, excel2latex

I am using excel2latex to create my tables, but when I am using beamer to create presentation file, it has error. My code is :

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx, color}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{booktabs}



  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{}
  \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Indices, Parameters and Decision Variables}
      \begin{tabular}{llc}
      \toprule
                  &       & Explanation \\
      \midrule
      \multirow{4}[0]{*}{Indices} & i, j, {i'},{j'} & graph nodes \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  k, {k'} & Convoys\\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  v & Convoys vehicles \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & ${v_k}$ & Index for the last vehicles in the convoy k \\
  \hline
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{14}[0]{*}{Parameters}} & N & Total number of convoys       or OD pairs. \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & M          & Total number nodes on the network       (intersections)\\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & $l_{i,j}$      & length of the arc (i,j) \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & $l_{k}^v$      & The length of the vehicle v in convoy k \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  $O_{ k}, D_{k}$   & The Origin and Destination points       of convoy k\\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & $r_{ k}$       & The arrival time of convoy k at       the Origin.  \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & $ f_{k}$       & The deadline for convoy k to       reach its destination. \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & $ S_{i,j}^k$       & The deadline for convoy k to       reach its destination. \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & $w_{ i}$       & The length of the convoy i. \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & $F_{i,j}$      & The traffic volume on edge (i,j).       \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & $A_{E\times E}$    & The Tabu List matrix, is one       where corresponding edges should \\
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & &not be occupied at the same time by more than one convoy. \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & $l_{k}$        & The total length of convoy k. \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & $\lambda_k$        & The waiting time interval at the origin       for convoy k. \\

  \hline

      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{7}[0]{*}{
  }} &  $X_{ i,j}^k$ & $ \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
  1 & \mbox{ If convoy k will pass through link (i,j) } &  \\
  0 & \mbox{Otherwise} & 
  \end{array}\right. $ \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & $Y_{k,k'}^i$        & $   \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
  1 & \mbox{ If convoy k will pass through link (i,j) } &  \\
  0 & \mbox{Otherwise} & 
  \end{array}\right. $  \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{Decision} & $Z_{i,j}^{k}$      & The time interval which       convoy k is on the edge (i,j) \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{Varialbes} & $t_{i}^{k,v}$     & The time when $v^th$       vehicle of  convoy k arrives at node i  \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & $Q_{i,j,i',j}^{k,k'}$  & $   \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
  1 & \mbox{ if Convoy k will pass the edge (i,j) before convoy {k'} pass edge (i',j')       } &  \\
  0 & \mbox{Otherwise} & 
  \end{array}\right. $ \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & $t_{i}^{k}$        & The time when convoy k will       arrive to node i \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & $B_k$          & The integer waiting component of       convoy k \\
      \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
  \end{table}%      
  \end{frame}
```

And the error that I got is :

! Undefined control sequence.
 \multirow

l.161 \end{frame}

?

Comment: @Izi It looks like you've got two accounts: as the StaffExchange staff (http://tex.stackexchange.com/contact) and they'll merge the accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include the multirow-package and it works!

```
\usepackage{multirow}
```

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't recognize me as the person who asked this question, but I got my answer.

Comment: @izi you can flag a moderator to combine your accounts - the flag button is just to the left of your name on the question. See also here: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1054/32374